# can someone examine the algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

This algorithm inputs a floating value `i` which represents the amount and returns the minimum number of coins required to pay that amount and returns an integer c .

> value c1 = 25 , c2 = 10 , c3 = 5 , c4 = 1

My code works perfectly all for inputs except when `i = 4.2` it should return 18 coins rather it returns 22 coins

```
i=i*100;

while (i>0) {
    if(i>=25) {
        c = (int) i/25;
        i= (int) i%25;
    }
    else if (i>=10 && i<25) {
        c = c + (int) i/10;
        i=(int) i%10;
    }

    else if(i>=5 && i<10) {
        c = c + (int) i/5;
        i = (int) i%5;
    }
    else if(i<5) {
        c = c + (int) i/1;
        i = (int) i%1;
    }
}

printf("%d\n",c);
```

Comment: 1. Format the code to make it readable. 2. use a debugger

Comment: Wow, centered?  And I thought the GNU style was tough to read.

Comment: The if need to contemplate the equal value, eg: else `if (i >= 10 && i < 25)`, the range is [ini, fin), close at the beginning, open at the end.

Comment: @NetVipeC YEAH but still wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is with floating point precision.

```
float i = 4.2;
i *= 100;
printf("%f\n", i);
```

Print: `419.999969` and not `4.2` as it should, in this case `419` is the value used in the coin problem resulting in 22 coins used `16 of 25`, `1 of 10`, `1 of 5` and `4 of 1` = `total 22`

Use: `i = round(i * 100);` instead of `i = i * 100;`

You need to contemplate the equal value, eg: else if (i >= 10 && i < 25), the range is [ini, fin), close at the beginning, open at the end. If you change the `else if` by `if` you don't need the `while loop`.

Final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int c = 0;
    float iv = 4.2;
    int i = round(iv * 100);

    printf("%d\n", i);
    if (i >= 25) {
        c += i / 25;
        i = i % 25;
    }
    if (i >= 10) {
        c += i / 10;
        i = i % 10;
    }
    if (i >= 5) {
        c += i / 5;
        i = i % 5;
    }
    if (i > 0) {
        c += i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

More info about 
[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)